# how to make an event stop overlapping a command

Tags: python, discord.py

I've had this problem for a while, trying to use both commands and events in one file.

I know that there's a function called process_commands(), but the bot doesn't seem to have this function. Is there anything I need to import though? (else than discord.ext and commands)

picture of code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdvj8.png

Comment: Hi Mathe, welcome to stack overflow.  Could you add some context and detail to your question?  It's not clear what you are working on (is it a discord bot?), what you are trying to achieve, or in what way the code is not working.  Also - it will be much easier to help if you post your code in a code block (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) rather than as a linked image.

Comment: Hey Simon.

Thanks for commenting! Yes it is a discord bot, and I'm trying to have both commands an events in a single file. 

I have found a solution, which is to open multiple codes/files at once when running the bot. It just seems a little primitive.

Do you know any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add `await client.process_commands(message)` on top of the on_message event

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message) 
    # do other stuff
```

also `message.send('...')` in your command doesnt work, it must be awaited since its a coroutine. ([Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=send#discord.ext.commands.Context.send))

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx): # ctx instead of message
    await ctx.send("test")
```